# How to count occurrences within coin change problem

Tags: python

I have a bunch of cash notes `[5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 500]` given a value `x`, find the least possible notes that sum to that value, and then return the occurrence of those notes within a array. We are assuming that we can only receive numbers divisible by `min(cash) = 5`

For e.g.

```
x = 5:
    return [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Receiving 5 with the least amount of notes, and 5 occurs once.

Another e.g.

```
x = 1000
    return [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```

As the least amount of notes is two 500's. They occur twice.
This should be easy and probably is, I think I'm nearly there but can't seem to get around the final hurdle.

My code so far is:

```
def atm(x, cash=[5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 500]):
    count_5 = 0
    count_10 = 0
    count_20 = 0
    count_50 = 0
    count_100 = 0
    count_500 = 0
    if x == 5:
        return [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    elif x == 10:
        return [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    elif x == 20:
        return [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
    elif x == 50:
        return [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
    elif x == 100:
        return [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
    elif x == 500:
        return [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

    flag = None
    for c in cash:
        if c < x:
            flag = c
    temp_balance = round(x - flag, 2)

    if flag or temp_balance == 5:
        count_5 += 1
    if flag or temp_balance == 10:
        count_10 += 1
    if flag or temp_balance == 20:
        count_20 += 1
    if flag or temp_balance == 50:
        count_50 += 1
    if flag or temp_balance == 100:
        count_100 += 1
    if flag or temp_balance == 500:
        count_500 += 1

    return [count_5, count_10, count_20, count_50, count_100, count_500]


print(atm(150))
```

And what this returns is `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` which is not correct as I was expecting `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]`. What have I done wrong here and how to fix this?

I have partly used this YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JwdenBGmEo&ab_channel=KevinNaughtonJr.) however I have not used recursion.

I am also thinking of time complexity with this but at a early stage of creating more efficient algorithms. So if there's a better way instead of all these `if` `elif` statements then I'd like to learn from it.

Comment: I think you should get it working for 2 size notes..  i.e. 5 and 10,  and make it work for 5, 10 and 15,  then progress to the rest.  Don't worry about optimising it unt il you have a working solution. Plus you don't explain what `cash=[100, 50, 20]` is for.

Comment: I did not finish typing that `cash` default value correctly - fixed now. Ok, I'll try that and see where it goes

Comment: You only change 'temp_balance' once, so it will work for all of those examples.. then you just need to work out how to make it work for more

Comment: Why would you except `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]` when you would need 4 notes of value 100?

Comment: Edited, mistakes in question as I was thinking and typing. To get the least amount of notes for 150, this would be one 100 and one 50. Hence [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem of why you're seeing `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` (all 1's) is because your if statement has an error in it:

```
    if flag or temp_balance == 100:
```

This doesn't check if `flag is 100 or temp_balance is 100` it just checks if `flag is non-zero OR temp_balance is 100`, which will be the case every iteration.

Some other issues:

1. You have a `cash` parameter as input, but that doesn't necessarily correlate to the variables you used to keep track of the number of notes. You should find some way to track your notes based off the initial `cash` array. This can be something as simple as creating another array of the same length initialized with all 0's that holds the count of notes for the cash at each position. `note_count = [0 for _ in cash]`
2. Don't try to pull out the special case for exact matches. It just makes your code longer.
3. You can't use a greedy algorithm for this problem. You need something like dynamic programming for it to work properly. Consider your cash values `cash=[10, 50, 150, 200]` and you have `x=300`. If you used a greedy algorithm you would take 3 notes, 1 note of 200 and 2 notes of 50, but you can do it in 2 notes of 150.

---

### Time complexity (represented in big O notation like `O(n)`)is about how execution length grows as a factor of some input

The most typical case is for `n` to represent the number of items your algorithm iterates over (but it can represent something else like the bit length of the input for an algorithm that performs some bitwise mathematical operations). If your cash system is upper bounded by some number, say 10, then the loop that you use to find the next cash note will become a constant as you have a constant number of iterations to make to find the next note to divide by. In fact, in your case you have a constant time complexity regarding the choice of a note because you have explicitly written out the 6 cash note cases. What is variable here is your amount input, so your time complexity would derive from how long it would take to reduce the given amount to 0. You should be able to find that number fairly easily (think about what is the amount that would require the most number of notes and then think about all amounts greater than that).

### Time complexity is NOT about efficiency between two operations

When you talk about `if, else if` statements and how to make more efficient code, you may be correct in saying "one construct is more efficient or faster than another", but this is NOT what time complexity is about. Time complexity is about how execution length grows as a factor of some input. For example, you may be able to make a slightly more efficient "choice" construct by using a dictionary. A dictionary has constant time access, so no matter how many items are in the dictionary your time access is `O(1)`. But if you have a constant number of if/else statements then it is also `O(1)` because your if/else statements do NOT grow. It may be slower, but it's complexity is still constant.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll look all this stuff up, appreciate the help

Comment: on #3 you can use a greedy algorithm for the problem as it is stated.  If it needed to solve for arbitrary cash systems that would be different. in fact in most real money systems, the greedy algorithm yields optimal solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop over the `cash` values, subtracting them from `x`:

```py
def atm(x, cash=[10, 20, 50, 100, 500]):
    ret = [0] * len(cash)
    for idx,d in enumerate(reversed(cash)):
        while x >= d:
            x -= d
            ret[idx] += 1
    
    return list(reversed(ret))
        
print(atm(450))
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 4, 0]
```

Comment: I believe there is an issue with using this greedy algorithm for calculating the least amount of notes. Consider you have `cash=[10, 50, 150, 200]` and `x=300`. This would be 3 notes given your algorithm, but it could be done in 2.

Comment: Although the cash list given by the OP is optimised to allow a greedy algorithm to also produce a minimum number of notes. Currencies come in these denominations to allow cashiers to give change using this algorithm.

Comment: That may be well and true, but he did state "find the least possible notes that sum to that value", and given that `cash` is a parameter it can't be guaranteed to work with a greedy algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you need (Sorry for rewriting your code):

```
def atm(x, cash=[100, 50, 20]):
xCpy = x

notes = [0 for x in range (len(cash))]

i = len(cash)-1
for note in cash:
    while note <= xCpy:
        xCpy -= note

        notes[i] += 1
    i -= 1

return notes

print(atm(40))
```